# HighCharts, column chart overlappiing issue . If same date is on x-axis on diffrent time, then also iam getting overlaaped columns in my column chart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

i'm using Highcharts api to plot the column chart for ,

y-axis  using  integer  and on x-axis timesatamp.

If data on x-axis with same date but diffrent time, column are overlapping but on mouse hover recognize that two points are plotted.

But actually i wanted to see columns without overlapping.

here i have my drawMychart.js

```
function draw(jsonData, start_date, end_date) {
chart = new Highcharts.Chart({

        chart : {
            type : 'column',
            renderTo : 'content',
            plotBorderWidth : 1,
        },

        legend : {
            enabled : false
        },

        title : {
            text : 'My Chart Updates'
        },

        xAxis : {
            type : "datetime",
            //tickInterval : 3600 * 1000, // 1 hours

            min : start_date, // X axis minimum days data start , for now only
            // 2 days
            max : end_date, // X axis maximum limit for date , current date
            startOnTick : true,
            endOnTick : true,

            title : {
                text : 'Time Intervals of Executed Job'
            },
        // labels: {
        // format: '{value}'
        // },

        },

        // yAxis : {
        //  title : {
        //      text : ''
        //  },
        //  labels : {
        //      enabled : false
        //
        //  },
        //  maxPadding : 0.03,
        // },

        tooltip : {

            formatter : function() {
                var date = new Date(this.point.x);
                return "Job Run Time :" + date.toString() + '<br/> '
                        + "Task Id: " + this.point.taskId + '<br/> '
                        + "Compaingn Count:" + this.point.y;
            },

        // ToDo , will check If its possible to use the <table> within formatter

        // useHTML: true,
        // headerFormat: '<table>',
        // pointFormat:
        // // '<tr><th>Job Run time :</th><td> {point.x}</td></tr>' +
        // '<tr><th>Task Id:</th><td>{point.taskId}</td></tr>' +
        // '<tr><th>Compaingn Id:</th><td>{point.compId}</td></tr>' +
        // '<tr><th>Compaign count:</th><td>{point.y}</td></tr>',
        // footerFormat: '</table>',
        // followPointer: true
        },

        // plotOptions : {
        //  bubble : {
        //      minSize : 10,
        //      maxSize : 15,
        //  },
        //  series : {
        //      dataLabels : {
        //          enabled : true,
        //          format : '{point.y}'
        //      }
        //  }
        // },
        plotOptions: {
             column: {
                 pointWidth : 10
             }
         },
        series : [ {
            data : jsonData,
            color : "green",
             pointWidth: 28
        } ]
    });
```

please refer this  fiddle link

In this fiddle link ,i have chart with two data points , on same x-axis but diffrent y axis.
https://jsfiddle.net/shrwn1a6/2/

[image]

In above screen shot see the overlapped columns.

Help will really appreciated.

Comment: Your code is not complete and the problem can't be reproduced. Read [how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Your starting point can be this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/shrwn1a6/ I can guess that the problem is with the pointWidth - which is just too big.

Comment: Thanks morganfree for your suggetion, please take this updated fiddle link [https://jsfiddle.net/shrwn1a6/2/] , here tried with modifying the pointWidth but its still overlapping on single column.

Comment: You have points with the same x values - if you put them in the same series, they will be rendered in the same place. If you want to have columns next to each other (points with the same x value), you need to put them in different series. https://jsfiddle.net/shrwn1a6/3/

Comment: But i will get  only one single json data,  means  all the  x axis and y axis data is pushed into one single data how i can devide into two separate series.

Comment: That depens on how your json look like. Basically, you need to loop through the json and divide the data so they will not include repeats.

Comment: Other than using multiple series , do i have any other way to over come the overlapping issue, Because my json having same datetime object with diffrence in some hours and minutes .

Comment: I do not understand. How can you have the same datetime with difference in some hours and minutes? If there is a difference, there will not be any overlappes https://jsfiddle.net/shrwn1a6/4/

Comment: Ok fine i will agree with you,  let consider two different datetime object with some diffrence in seconds , iam not able to see diffrent columns on chart.